# Appending a line to a force directed graph and applying a transform using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a force directed graph in D3 that renders correctly on load from a web socket.  I am tasked with adding or removing links and nodes to and from this graph depending on subsequent web socket messages.  The problem I am having is that when I pan or zoom the graph a transform gets applied.  I don't know how to apply that transform to the newly added links or nodes.  As a result the links that get added are dependent on the original cx cy positions of the source and destination nodes.  Here is the code in it's entirety.  Hopefully someone can clue me in as to how to apply the transform to the newly added links.

Code Edited for brevity as requested:

```
    var DataPlane = (function() {

//This method gets called when a link is either added or removed from the svg via web socket.
var remapDataPlane = function(data) {
    var dpData = $.parseJSON(data);
    ...
    if (dpData.addedLinks.length > 0) {
        //get the svg
        var parentSvg = d3.select("#app_dataPlane svg").select("g")
        var svg = parentSvg.select("g");

        //this portion gets the transform that has been applied to the svg group element.
        var trans = svg.attr("transform");

        //get a list of switches from svg
        var svgSwitches = d3.selectAll(".switch");
        //Process unidirectional and bidirectional links -- BEGIN
        var bidLinks = [];
        var uniLinks = [];
        var pairs = [];
        var idx = 0;


        function hasMatchingNode(element, index, array) {
            return (element.src.dpid !== this.src.dpid && element.src.dpid === this.dst.dpid && element.dst.dpid === this.src.dpid);
        }

        function parseLinks(element, index, array) {
            var node = array.filter(hasMatchingNode, element);
            if (node.length > 0) {
                var match = array.indexOf(node.pop());
                array.splice(match, 1);
            } else {
                uniLinks.push(element);
                array.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
        dpData.addedLinks.map(parseLinks);
        if (dpData.addedLinks != undefined) {
            dpData.addedLinks.forEach(function(item) {
                item["nature"] = "bidirectional";
            });
            uniLinks.forEach(function(item) {
                item["nature"] = "unidirectional";
            });

            //Links are added in pairs to represent bidirectional nature.  I elminate duplicate links from the data and merge them with unidirectional links here.
            $.merge(dpData.addedLinks, uniLinks);
        }

        //For each link being added to the graph 
        for (var i = 0; i <= dpData.addedLinks.length - 1; i++) {

            //Get the name of the source node for the link and it's corresponding coordinates
            var srcName = 'switch_' + dpData.addedLinks[i].src.dpid;
            var srcC = document.getElementById(srcName);
            var srcCx = +srcC.getAttribute('cx');
            var srcCy = +srcC.getAttribute('cy');
            var srcCtm = srcC.getCTM();
            var srcCoords = getScreenCoords(srcCx, srcCy, srcCtm);

            //Get the name of the destination node for the link and it's corresponding coordinates
            var dstName = 'switch_' + dpData.addedLinks[i].dst.dpid;
            var dstC = document.getElementById(dstName);
            var dstCx = +dstC.getAttribute('cx');
            var dstCy = +dstC.getAttribute('cy');
            var dstCtm = dstC.getCTM();
            var dstCoords = getScreenCoords(dstCx, dstCy, dstCtm);

            //Append the line to the graph using the coordinates derived from the Cx & Cy coordinates
            var link = svg.append("line")
                .attr("x1", srcCoords.x)
                .attr("y1", srcCoords.y)
                .attr("x2", dstCoords.x)
                .attr("y2", dstCoords.y)
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("id", function(d) {
                    return "name_" + dpData.addedLinks[i].dst.dpid + dpData.addedLinks[i].src.dpid;
                })
                .style("stroke-width", 2)
                //Set Style for unidirectional otherwise grey
                .style("stroke", function(d) {
                    if (d != undefined && d.nature == "unidirectional") {
                        return "green";
                    }
                })
                // **** This is where I try and apply the transform to the link ****
                .attr("transform", trans)                   
        }
    }

    function getScreenCoords(x, y, ctm) {
        var xn = ctm.e + x * ctm.a;
        var yn = ctm.f + y * ctm.d;
        return {
            x: xn,
            y: yn
        };
    }
};      

// Initial code omitted for brevity as requested

return {
    drawDataPlane: drawDataPlane,
    remapDataPlane: remapDataPlane
};
   })();
```

Sample of SVG Elements:

```
    <svg width="814" height="305" pointer-events="all">
<g>
    <g transform="translate(6.568073042618323,138.38858706474264) scale(0.8420541187522115)">
        <rect width="1628" height="610" fill="white"></rect>
        <line class="link" id="name_00:00:00:00:00:00:00:0100:00:00:00:00:00:00:03" x1="427.59429499296965" y1="125.07073054436019" x2="375.8732495447546" y2="138.7148361886131" style="stroke-width: 2px;"></line>
        <line class="link" id="name_00:00:00:00:00:00:00:0200:00:00:00:00:00:00:01" x1="375.8732495447546" y1="138.7148361886131" x2="400.55190412548484" y2="186.17410516927373" style="stroke-width: 2px;"></line>
        <circle r="6" id="switch_00:00:00:00:00:00:00:02" class="switch" fill="#15a9ff" cx="400.55190412548484" cy="186.17410516927373"></circle>
        <circle r="6" id="switch_00:00:00:00:00:00:00:03" class="switch" fill="#15a9ff" cx="427.59429499296965" cy="125.07073054436019"></circle>
        <circle r="6" id="switch_00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01" class="switch selectedSwitch" fill="#15a9ff" cx="375.8732495447546" cy="138.7148361886131"></circle>
    </g>
</g>
```

Panning/Zooming Function:

```
    function redraw() {
        svg.attr("transform",
            "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")"); /* skewX(30) */
    }
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of the way the svg elements are currently, and which portions are a problem? This is a bit much in terms of code to go through, it'd be good if you could either narrow down the problem or give some sample output showing the problem in more detail.

Comment: What does your panning/zooming function look like?